Existence, uniqueness and smoothness of solutions of the heat equation
Consider the classical heat equation on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) & =  &-\Delta u(x,t),\\
u(x,0) & = & u_0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I use the convention $\Delta f = -\mathbb{div}(\nabla f) = -\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i^2}$. We look for weak solutions in $L_{1,0}^2(\Omega) = \overline{\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\Omega)}$ for the $L_1^2$ Sobolev norm. Then, it is known that the solution exists at all time, is unique, and smooth when $u_0$ is smooth (and thus is a strong solution).
In the Chapter 6 of "Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles", Kobayashi proves the same result of existence/uniqueness/smoothness of solutions in a different setting (see Theorem 6.8.25). Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle on a Kähler manifold $(X,\omega)$ and $h$ a smooth Hermitian metric, we call $F(h)$ the associated curvature form. Let $\Lambda$ the contraction with respect to $\omega$.
If $h_0$ is a smooth Hermitian metric on a holomorphic vector bundle $E$, we have existence at all time, uniqueness and smoothness of the heat equation,
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
h^{-1}(t)\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t) & =  &-(i\Lambda F(h(t)) + cI_E),\\
h(0) & = & h_0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Here, $c$ is some topological constant which doesn't really matter in the problem I have. This equation is locally similar to the classical heat equation because if we set $s(t) = h^{-1}(t)\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t)$ (which is a smooth section of the endomorphisms of $E$), then,
$$
\frac{\partial(i\Lambda F(h) + cI_E)}{\partial t}(t) = \Delta_{h(t)}s(t),
$$
where $\Delta_{h(t)}$ is a non-negative elliptic operator of order $2$ on the space of smooth sections of Hermitian endomrohpisms of $E$.
My question is : Is there a generalisation of this result to more general elliptic PDE ? Concretely, if $(M,g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, $S$ is the space of smooth sections of symmetric/Hermitian endomorphisms of some real/complex vector bundle $E$, $P : S \rightarrow S$ is a smooth map (for some Sobolev/Hölder/$\mathcal{C}^k$ norms on the first and the second $S$) such that each linearisation $dP(s) : S \rightarrow S$ is non-negative and elliptic of order $2$ and $s_0 \in S$, is there existence at all time, uniqueness and smootheness of the associated heat equation ?
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}(t) & =  &-P(s(t)),\\
s(0) & = & s_0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I am more a complex geometer than a Riemannian analyst so I don't have a lot of references about elliptic PDE, please let me know if you know any book/article that may help me.
